# Filtering an icon from an array of icon strings for re-render

Tags: reactjs, icons

I'm trying to take an e.target.value which is an icon and filter it out from an array in state, and re-render the new state minus the matching icons. I can't seem to stringify it to make a match. I tried pushing to an array and toString(). [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q6jyj2yv6)

✈ ["✈", "♘", "✈", "♫", "♫", "☆", "♘", "☆"]

Here is the code snippet (Parent)

```
removeMatches(icon) {
 const item = icon;
 const iconsArray = this.props.cardTypes;
 const newIconsArray =iconsArray.filter(function(item) {
  item !== icon
  })
this.setState({ cardTypes: newIconsArray });
}
```

This is a function in the parent component Cards, when the child component is clicked I pass a value into an onClick. Below is a click handler in the Child component

```
handleVis(e) {
 const item = e.target.value
this.props.removeMatches(item)
 }
```

Comment: There's some information missing here. Can you point out the part of your code you talking about?

Comment: I added code snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's nothing really different about filtering an "icon" string array from any other strings. Your example works like this:

```
const icons = ["✈", "♘", "✈", "♫", "♫", "☆", "♘", "☆"]
const icon = "✈";
const filteredIcons = icons.filter(i => i !== icon);
filteredIcons // ["♘", "♫", "♫", "☆", "♘", "☆"]
```

Your CodeSandbox example has some other issues, though:

- Your `Card.js` component invokes `this.props.removeMatches([item])` but the `removeMatches` function treats the argument like a single item, not an array.
- Your `Cards.js` `removeMatches()` function filters `this.props.cardTypes` (with the previously mentioned error about treating the argument as a single item not an array) but does not assign the result to anything. `Array.filter()` returns a new array, it does not modify the original array.
- Your `Cards.js` is rendering `<Card>` components from `props.cardTypes`, this means that `Cards.js` is only rendering the cards from the props it is given, so it cannot filter that prop from inside the component. You have a few options:

  1. Pass the `removeMatches` higher up to where the cards are stored in state, in `Game.js` as `this.state.currentCards`, and filter it in `Game.js` which will pass the filtered `currentCards` back down to `Cards.js`.

     ```
     // Game.js
     removeMatches = (items) => {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
         currentCards: prevState.currentCards.filter(card => items.indexOf(card) == -1)
       }));
     }
     // ...
     <Cards cardTypes={this.state.currentCards} removeMatches={this.removeMatches} />

     // Cards.js
     <Card removeMatches={this.props.removeMatches}/>

     // Card.js -- same as it is now
     ```
  2. Move `Cards.js` `props.cardTypes` into state (ex `state.currentCards`) within `Cards.js`, then you can filter it out in `Cards.js` and render from `state.currentCards` instead of `props.cardTypes`. To do this you would also need to hook into `componentWillReceiveProps()` to make sure that when the `currentCards` are passed in as `prop.cardTypes` from `Game.js` that you update `state.currentCards` in `Cards.js`. That kind of keeping state in sync with props can get messy and hard to follow, so option 1 is probably better.

     ```
     // Cards.js
     state = { currentCards: [] }
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (this.props.cardTypes !== nextProps.cardTypes) {
         this.setState({ currentCards: nextProps.cardTypes });
       }
     }
     removeMatches = (items) => {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
         currentCards: prevState.currentCards.filter(card => items.indexOf(card) == -1)
       }));
     }
     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           { this.state.currentCards.map(card => {
             // return rendered card
           }) }
         </div>
       );
     }
     ```
  3. Store all the *removed cards* in state in `Cards.js` and filter `cardTypes` against `removedCards` before you render them (you will also need to reset `removedCards` from `componentWillReceiveProps` whenever the current cards are changed):

     ```
     // Cards.js
     state = { removedCards: [] }
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (this.props.cardTypes !== nextProps.cardTypes) {
         this.setState({ removedCards: [] });
       }
     }
     removeMatches = (items) => {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
         removedCards: [...prevState.removedCards, ...items]
       }));
     }
     render() {
       const remainingCards = this.props.cardTypes.filter(card => {
         return this.state.removedCards.indexOf(card) < 0;
       });
       return (
         <div>
           { remainingCards.map(card => {
             // return rendered card
           })}
         </div>
       );
     }
     ```

As you can see, keeping state in one place in `Game.js` is probably your cleanest solution.

You can see all 3 examples in this forked CodeSandbox (the second 2 solutions are commented out): https://codesandbox.io/s/6yo42623p3

Comment: So, using option 1,  I have to pass the event handler all the way from Game.js, to Cards.js to Card.js? <Cards onClick={this.props.removeMatches}? The way I'm attempting now, I get "error this.props.removeMatches is not a function"

Comment: 'this' is pointing to Card inside the handeVis function, how do get the removeMatches function to the scope where I can pass the clicked item

Comment: Yes, you need to pass `removeMatches` explicitly from `Game.js` to `<Cards>` to `<Card>`. The pass-through in `Cards.js` can simply be `<Card removeMatches={this.props.removeMatches}>`, in other words you don't need to create a handler function in the middle and explicitly invoke it. Just pass from props to props.

Comment: I don't get it, if I'm not passing e.target.value to handleVis function in <Card /> and invoking the removeMatches function there, how do I get the value to filter to where it needs to be?

Comment: No I'm not saying you change anything in `Card.js`, you still have a `onClick` handler there that invokes `this.props.removeMatches([e.target.value])`.

Comment: I tried an <Card onClick={(e) =>this.props.removeMatches([e.target.value])/>, no errors just no change in UI

Comment: You need the other parts too... see https://codesandbox.io/s/6yo42623p3

Comment: Sorry, React confuses me sometimes, [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q6jyj2yv6)

Comment: In your last CodeSandbox you've removed the `onClick` from the `div` inside `Card.js`, but you need that, and in `Cards.js` instead of rendering `<Card onClick={...}>` you just need to pass the `removeMatches` prop like `<Card removeMatches={this.props.removeMatches}>`... this is all in the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yo42623p3) I posted, take a look

Comment: Got it,thanks Aaron, I'll be reading this over and over to understand how this works and to understand my faulty logic. I keep putting the props in the wrong places in different components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168952/discussion-between-kevin-t-and-aaron).